# Looping through extra data in D3 Directional Force Layout

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nested-loops

I am new to D3 and it looks pretty cool. I thought I'd try building something using the Directional Force Layout.

**What I am trying to do**

I am creating a json object via a for loop to add all my items ready for use on force.start(). That works fine. However I want to add more data via a different json source. To do that I have another loop inside the first loop to add more data based on data in my first loop (see code).

**How far I've got**

I've console logged and I can see that items are pushed into my json object however they do not get the correct attributes for force.nodes(); see:

```
group: 2
name: "Alt-J"
px: NaN
py: NaN
x: NaN
y: NaN
```

Why is this?
To me it seems like the diagram is built before loop has finished and the items are properly added.

Heres my code:

```
// Get the users top played artists
d3.json("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettopartists.gettopartists&user="+ username +"&api_key=be4ff3242bdb1d653517df99df39cfe2&format=json", function(error, graph) {
  // Loops through them and push them in nodes.names[]
  for (var i = 0; i < graph.topartists.artist.length; i++) { 
    var item = graph.topartists.artist[i];
    // Then get for each top artist their respect related artists
    d3.json("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist="+ item.name +"&api_key=be4ff3242bdb1d653517df99df39cfe2&format=json", function(error, related) {
        // Do this just for 5 item to reduce load
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < 5; i2++) { 
          var relatedItem = related.similarartists.artist[i2];
          console.log(i2);
          // Add those to our json object like with top artists
          nodes.names.push({ 
            "name" : relatedItem.name,
            "group" : 2
          });
          nodes.links.push({
            "source" : i + i2 ,
            "target" : 0
          });
        }
        console.log(nodes.names);
    });

    nodes.names.push({ 
        "name" : item.name,
        "group" : 1
    });
    nodes.links.push({
        "source" : i,
        "target" : 0
    });
  }
  force
      .nodes(nodes.names)
      .links(nodes.links)
      .distance(20)
      .start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that `d3.json` is asynchronous. That is, the callback is not executed immediately, but when the call to get the JSON returns. What this means is that the block of code to initialise and start the force layout is run before the nested `d3.json` calls return and add the data.

This is not a problem as such -- you can certainly add new items to the arrays you give to `force.nodes()` and `force.links()`. The problem is that the positions of these new items are not initialised, and that only happens on `force.start()`. So after adding new nodes/links, you need to start the force layout again.

You should be able to fix this in your code by declaring `force` further up and calling `force.start()` at the end of each nested callback.

Comment: Thank you Lars. I will try adjusting my code soon. I see your answers coming up a lot on D3 questions. Do you know any good online resources /tutorials? Cheers

Comment: The tutorials linked on the D3 website are usually a good place to start and cover a lot of material.